# Regarding using cache in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I am using MVC3 and getting country table from database and storing in cache. First time it get the data from caching but when I refresh the page its give me only datatable schema only. It give me only fields countryid,countryname, countrycode. But it dont give me data.

```
 DataTable dt_Country = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Countries"];
        if (dt_Country == null)
        {
            DataTable dt_State1 = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ConstantsCountriesSelectAll", con);
            SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ada.Fill(dt_State1);


            HttpContext.Current.Cache["Countries"] = dt_State1;
            dt_Country = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Countries"];
        }
        //dt_Country = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Countries"];
        return dt_Country;
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the connection before putting the data table in cache?  It might be that the connection is closing at some unknown point?